# Detecting which element has been changed/keyup

Tags: jquery

From this code, how can I detect which element has been changed/keyup?

```
$("select, input").on('change keyup', function() {
    ...
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `this` (see below).

The `this` is the instance of the affected `HTMLElement` (the target of the event). To get the tag, use `this.tagName`:

```js
$("select, input").on('change keyup', function() {
    console.log('Affected element:', this.tagName, this.getAttribute('id'));
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<input type="text" value="one" id="one">
<br>
<input type="text" value="two" id="two">
<br>
<select id="cars">
  <option value="volvo">Volvo</option>
  <option value="saab">Saab</option>
  <option value="mercedes">Mercedes</option>
  <option value="audi">Audi</option>
</select>
```

Comment: Ok, looks working but how can I get the tag name please ?

Comment: The this is the instance of the `HTMLElement`. To get the tag, use `this.tagName`. See updated answer.

Comment: how to current value of selected or input value?

Answer (score -1):

Besides `this` (which doesn't work for arrow functions) you can use the `event` variable that's passed to the function:

```js
$("select, input").on('change keyup', (e) => {
    console.log('Affected element:', e.currentTarget);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<input type="text" value="one" id="one">
<br>
<input type="text" value="two" id="two">
<br>
<select id="cars">
  <option value="volvo">Volvo</option>
  <option value="saab">Saab</option>
  <option value="mercedes">Mercedes</option>
  <option value="audi">Audi</option>
</select>
```

Comment: Use the "Ask A Question" button in the upper right.

Comment: The question is **how can I detect which element has been changed/keyup**  My code logs the element.  The question is **not** what is the value of the element.